# Assign multiple columns by reference using character vectors in join

Tags: r, data.table

Trying to create new columns during a join with variable column names on both RHS and LHS. Here is a MWE:

```r
dt1 <- data.table(id = c(1,2), year = c(2001, 1999))
dt2 <- data.table(year = c(2001, 2002, 1998, 1999), id = c(1,1,2,2), a=c(50, 100, 30, 22), b=c(1,2,3,4))

cols <- c("a", "b")
t <- 1
dt1[, match_year := year + 1]
```

Was expecting this to work:

```
dt1[dt2, on = .(id, match_year = year), 
    (paste0(cols, "_t", t)) := get(paste0("i.", cols))][]
```

```
   id year match_year a_t1 b_t1
1:  1 2001       2002  100  100
2:  2 1999       2000   NA   NA
```

No error message but seems like assignment only uses the first element in the list, `b_t1` should be 2.

This works, but is not as nice

```
dt1[dt2, on = .(id, match_year = year), 
    (paste0(cols, "_t", t)) := list(i.a, i.b)][]
```

```
   id year match_year a_t1 b_t1
1:  1 2001       2002  100    2
2:  2 1999       2000   NA   NA
```

Only way I figured out with variable names on both LHS and RHS is using eval(), but that is very hard to read.

```
txt <- paste0("dt1[dt2, on = .(id, match_year = year), ",
              "c(", paste0("\"", cols, "_t", t, "\"", collapse = ", "), ") := ",
              "list(", paste0("i.", cols, collapse = ", "), ")][]")
eval(parse(text = txt))
```

```
   id year match_year a_t1 b_t1
1:  1 2001       2002  100    2
2:  2 1999       2000   NA   NA
```

I'm using `data.table 1.12.7 IN DEVELOPMENT built 2019-10-29 16:48:24 UTC;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this be an improvment?

```
dt1[, (paste0(cols, "_t", t)) := dt2[.SD, on = .(id, year = match_year), mget(cols)]]
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually, it was just me not knowing about `mget()`. Replacing `get` with `mget` makes the first option work!